# Amazon S3 PHP Photo Upload issue

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am developing an application which allows people to upload photos to an Amazon S3 instance.

Though I have just edited my PHP config variables to allow a maximum of 10mb per image, my webapp returns a 500 server error without any response whenever I try to upload a photo below but close to that 10mb maximum (like 9.4mb).

The projects is made up of a webapp built using NodeJS and a Laravel PHP API. The file upload runs via this webapp.

I would very much appreciate any idea on what I could do to resolve this or any experiences with AWS and photo upload.

Thanks!

Comment: A 500 is pretty much every error. And without error messages there is really not much we can do...

Comment: I am wondering if you are uploading it directly to Amazon, or via your PHP script. In the first case, there isn't any reason to edit your PHP config variables, and in the second case you should go for the first case.

Comment: Hi Ivar, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, I dont get any more than a 500 either, which is what makes this so difficult to debug. The project is based on a NodeJS webapp sending them to a Laravel API which stores them.

Comment: PHP will log errors to the PHP error logs. PHP error logs are setup in php.ini. Make sure that PHP error logging is enabled and the log file path exists and is writable. Repeat the steps that reproduce the 500 error and then look at the last few lines in the PHP log files.